# VPN Connects Active Directory Permissions don't follow

Tags: vpn, permissions

One user with a Windows 7 laptop connects to our Barracuda SSL VPN. When he goes to the mapped network drive and tries to save a file, create a folder, or do anything that requires more than Read-Only permission he gets an access denied warning. At the office he is able to save a file, create a folder, and all that. So somewhere after connecting to the VPN he loses his AD permissions.

To troubleshoot I've copied his permissions and that copied user is able to use the VPN with the correct access. Removed all his permissions, waited an hour, and then re-added them. No dice. Recreated his Windows user and the problem still remains. Logged in with a second user and then into the VPN with his user and it worked.

I'm just not sure where its losing the permissions when it connects to the VPN and he's the only user with this issue.